# C struct memory allocation on visual studio

Tags: c, memory, struct

I'm getting an access violation error on line 5 of the function:

```
newString->str = cpysource;
```

I'm trying to copy the char * to the values of the string.

```
typedef struct {
    char* str;
}String;
```

This is my `struct`.

```
String* CreateString(const char* source)
{
    int len1 = strlen(source);
    char* cpysource = (char*)malloc(len1 * sizeof(char));
    cpysource = source;
    String* newString = malloc(sizeof(String));
    newString->str = cpysource;
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: You're allocating `cpysource` and then immediately leaking it the line after by assigning `source` over top of it instead of doing a `strcpy`. Also you don't need to cast after `malloc` in C

Comment: `cpysource = source;` doesn't copy anything but the pointer. `cpysource` now points to the same memory location as `source`. You could just use `cpysource = strdup(source);` (and skip allocating space by hand)

Comment: also `malloc(len1 * sizeof(char))` --> `malloc(len1 * sizeof(char) + 1)` to leave room for the `NUL` terminator.

Comment: @StefanRiedel note: [`strdup` isn't officially part of C until C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) but it is POSIX. That said AFAIK it's generally available

Comment: what error are you getting? Edit your question and copy and paste it there.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc(len1 * sizeof(char))` does not allocate enough space for the string. You need space for the null character that terminates the string. Use:

```
char *cpysource = malloc((len+1) * sizeof *cpysource);
```

(`sizeof *cpysource` is 1, so this could also be `char *cpysource = malloc(len+1);`. However, keeping it as above automatically adapts in case `cpysource` is later changed to be a different type, such as a wide character type.)

`cpysource = source;` does not copy a string. Both `cpysource` and `source` are pointers, so this attempts to copy a pointer (by assignment). However, `source` points to `const char`, and `cpysource` points to `char`, so the compiler warns you about removing a qualifier. To copy the string, use:

```
strcpy(cpysource, source);
```

Comment: FWIW it's also probably worth mentioning that if they are going to do a custom `String` they should probably also store the length.

Comment: still having problem in this line  newString->str = cpysource; still having memory violation

Comment: That's the same problem. You need to ```strcpy``` the ```cpysource```, instead of assigning it.

Comment: @dentetorto are you checking the result of `malloc`? Reminder that when `malloc` fails it returns `NULL`

Comment: he is working , but i still cant assing the newString->str = cpysource; im still getting memory violation

Comment: @dentetorto https://godbolt.org/z/Wh39o91vT should work...

Comment: nop, still giving me the same error , thanks anyway

Comment: @xuman: Re “You need to strcpy the cpysource, instead of assigning it”: No, `cpysource` and `newString->str` are both pointers, and `newString->str` should be set to point to the allocated memory, which is what `cpysource` points to.

Comment: @dentetorto: `newString->str = cpysource;` is correct. Ensure you are compiling the source code you think you are compiling and the error message is actually for that line. That said, Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging or teaching service. It is for specific questions and answers, not for tracking what is going on with your program until it is fixed. It is up to you to learn how to program C from other materials, such as textbooks and courses.

Comment: @dentetorto FWIW there is a better way... https://godbolt.org/z/j85WfhTjf

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for helping , i didnt ask you to teach me, not even to help me track anything , im having a problem in that specific area and im trying to fix

Comment: @dentetorto: You asked a question about an error message on the `cpysource = source;` line. That has been answered. Now you are asking about a message on another line. That is not what Stack Overflow is for, not what its questions and answers are for, and not what is comments are for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so i think i made a mistake, the question was in line five of the function , im sry, the problem was always in this part